# Bootstrap - How to center images from top and bottom side in a bootstrap div class

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not able to center top padding for all aligned images in `<div class="photos text-center">`
I have already set background for the div. so it looks like border after centralizing images from all sides. please find the below link for code.

http://codepen.io/devendrasingh/pen/dGroGM

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading text-center">
   <h1 class="heading">Amitabh Bachchan</h1>
      <h5 class="heading">Shahenshah of Bollywood</h5>
</div> 
   <div class="photos text-center">
      <img src="http://i2.wp.com/celebritykick.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Amitabh-Bachchan-Childhood-pictures-1a.jpg" class="profile-pic image-responsive">
      <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-M406xYLxmxQ/TiP6cAVINQI/AAAAAAAABI4/WR5cdWO1h0s/s1600/4.jpg" class="profile-pic image-responsive">
      <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-TPBdiYqY2N4/TiP7S-QyKEI/AAAAAAAABJc/_WWCsdLZfIM/s1600/d.jpg" class="profile-pic image-responsive">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d0/23/e1/d023e15529ee609aec540e354b0617ef.jpg" class="profile-pic image-responsive">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Amitabh_Bachchan_December_2013.png/220px-Amitabh_Bachchan_December_2013.png" class="profile-pic image-responsive">
<p class="caption">Amitabh Bachchan photos from different ages.</p>
</div>
```

Note : Images should be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because there is one `p` tag with images.

Which is:

```
<p class="caption">Amitabh Bachchan photos from different ages.</p>
```

Make there `height:0`. like:

```
.caption {
    height: 0;
}
```

And give padding to image like following:

```
.profile-pic {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px 0; //here.
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ehd0a37/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Mvan/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <a href='#'>
    <img class='resize_fit_center'
      src='http://i.imgur.com/H9lpVkZ.jpg' />
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    line-height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.resize_fit_center {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent{
    position: relative;
}

.child{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```